# Get attribute of Child from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, hierarchy

I have prepared a [FIDDLE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2cda866fa4f8d808d799fad6ae7859bf)

I have a parent table which looks like below.

```
+----------+------------+
| material | Attachment |
+----------+------------+
| 101      | 1          |
| 102      | 2          |
| 201      | 4          |
| 202      | 4          |
| 301      | 2          |
+----------+------------+
```

Also the relation table as below

```
+--------+-------+
| parent | child |
+--------+-------+
| 101    | 201   |
| 101    | 202   |
| 101    | 204   |
| 101    | 205   |
| 102    | 301   |
| 102    | 302   |
+--------+-------+
```

Im trying to get the attachment of the child in the below format.
Expected output.

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| parent | child | Attachment |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 101    | 201   | 4          |
| 101    | 202   | 4          |
| 101    | 204   | Child NA   |
| 101    | 205   | Child NA   |
| 102    | 301   | 2          |
| 102    | 302   | Child NA   |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

I have tried this query. But i'm getting the attachment of Parent instead of child.

```
select c.parent,c.child,Attachment from parent p
join child c
on p.material=c.parent
```

Getting below.

```
+--------+-------+------------+
| parent | child | Attachment |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 101    | 201   | 1          |
| 101    | 202   | 1          |
| 101    | 204   | 1          |
| 101    | 205   | 1          |
| 102    | 301   | 2          |
| 102    | 302   | 2          |
+--------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a `left join`:

```
select r.parent, r.child, p.attachment
from relation r left join
     parent p
     on p.material = r.child;
```

This produces `NULL` rather than `'Child NA'`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef4e086aac654cc333f1c607c2f12e47) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. This works. But when there is extra row in `child` table say `112,401`. This query is returning that as well. But I want only those exists in `parent` table

Comment: @Avinash . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can write this:

```
   select c.parent, 
          c.child, 
          p.attachment
   from child c 
   left join parent p on p.material = c.child 
                         and 
                         c.parent IN (select material from parent);
```